# bundle display name is not changing in my game

Tags: xcode, game-center

I want to change my app display name. I already changed the name from old to new in info plist and general tab.
But it is still showing old name.
I dont know from where it is showing.
please help me

Answer (score 0):

If you double-click the project or workspace in the Project Navigator, and change the name there, Xcode will show you a panel of where it's going to automatically change the name. You shouldn't have to change it in `info.plist`.